# How to create an (always changing) branch in a git-controlled project

Tags: git, version-control

I have a script which I use git to control versioning. Now, I also use branching for some exclusive style, such as a module.

Now, I want to create a branch for comments. This branch will be always updating, because I write new codes and these codes then must be brought into the branch for them to get commented and documented.

Now, how should I keep updating it? Is there a proper way?

My current solution is creating and re-creating the branch on each stage. Currently I do this:

```
git checkout -b comments
```

I then write comments and then:

```
git checkout master
git merge comments
```

Then I start to write codes again, and after several days, I would be back for commenting the rest of the un-documented codes:

```
git branch -D comments
git checkout -b comments
```

And write comments and then repeat the process...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of constantly deleting and recreating the `comments` branch, just merge `master` back into it.

```
git checkout comments
git merge master
```

Over time, you'll get a history that looks something like

```
  * --- * ----------- * --- * -- * ------ * -- * (comments)
 /       \           /            \      /
* -- * -- * -- * -- * -- * -- * -- * -- * -- * -- * (master)
```

where the first `/` indicates the initial creation of the branch, and subsequent `/`
mark merges from `master`. Each `\` reflects a merge into `master`.